# Azure Databricks Delta Lake tables to Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Here is the scenario:

- the source data is stored in Azure Cosmos DB.
- We will create ETL pipeline in ADB to push the data in ADLS and store in Delta format using the medallion architecture.
- We will consume the data in Power BI Embedded.

We are using Azure Databricks connector is Power BI and using the Silver / Gold layer delta tables as a source in Power BI and using Direct Query to visualize. This is having a very slow performance in Power BI.

Is this approach correct? Or should we use some other approach.

Please clarify what is delta sharing and Databricks SQL. Is this something shall we try?